# Where and how to pass the `--force` option to chocolatey in a config file?

Tags: chocolatey

Where and how to pass the `--force` option to chocolatey in a config file?

```
<package
        id="autohotkey.portable" 
        version="2.0-a122"
        />
```

neither `installArguments="--force"` nor `packageParameters="--force"` seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add it in your config file. The only way to force it is to add it in the command by forehand.

`choco install packages.config --force`

There is actually a feature request for this on GitHub. You might want to tickle the ticket a bit if you want this to be implemented.
https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/760